# Parsing Json with multiple "levels" with Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a json file from an api call.

I have found this code that fits my need and trying to adapt it to what I want:

```
import math, urllib2, json, re


def download():
    graph = {}
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://fx.priceonomics.com/v1/rates/?q=1")
    jsrates = json.loads(page.read())

    pattern = re.compile("([A-Z]{3})_([A-Z]{3})")
    for key in jsrates:
        matches = pattern.match(key)
        conversion_rate = -math.log(float(jsrates[key]))
        from_rate = matches.group(1).encode('ascii','ignore')
        to_rate = matches.group(2).encode('ascii','ignore')
        if from_rate != to_rate:
            if from_rate not in graph:
                graph[from_rate] = {}
            graph[from_rate][to_rate] = float(conversion_rate)
    return graph
```

And I've turned it into:

```
import math, urllib2, json, re


def download():
    graph = {}
    page = urllib2.urlopen("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries")
    jsrates = json.loads(page.read())

    for pattern in jsrates['result'][0]['MarketName']:
    for key in jsrates['result'][0]['Ask']:
        matches = pattern.match(key)
        conversion_rate = -math.log(float(jsrates[key]))
        from_rate = matches.group(1).encode('ascii','ignore')
        to_rate = matches.group(2).encode('ascii','ignore')
        if from_rate != to_rate:
            if from_rate not in graph:
                graph[from_rate] = {}
            graph[from_rate][to_rate] = float(conversion_rate)
    return graph
```

Now the problem is that there is multiple level in the json "Result > 0, 1,2 etc"

[json screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68rcp.png)

```
for key in jsrates['result'][0]['Ask']:
```

I want the zero to be able to be any number, I don't know if thats clear.
So I could get all the ask price to match their marketname.

I have shortened the code so it doesnt make too long of a post.

Thanks
PS: sorry for the english, its not my native language.

Comment: Do you understand the code? What is the actual question? When you say you "want the zero to be able to be any number", how do you intend to specify which number to use? Or, perhaps, did you want to repeat the process for each each valid index? It's hard to guess what you mean.

Comment: Hi, yes what I meant was that I would like to be able to repeat the process for each valid index. That I could get the "ask" value for all the json and not just the first one.

Comment: `for key in jsrates['result'][0]['Ask']:` is incorrect (according to the screenshot) since that is a `float` (which is not *iterable*). You could have `result_list = jsrates["result"]` and then `for result_index, result in enumerate(result_list):` and then handle every result (like `result["Ask"]` or `result["MakretName"]`). `result_index` is the index (the **0** that you mentioned) of the current result in the result list. Also, the indenting in the 2nd snippet is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that, I'm just learning python for a couple of weeks for a class project, so it is mostly trial and errors for now.

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks a lot it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all of the result values that are returned, ignoring the meaningless numeric index:

```
for result in jsrates['result'].values():
    ask = result.get('Ask')
    if ask is not None:
        # Do things with your ask...
```